# Lenovo G50-70 Bluetooth driver is installed but cannot find devices

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

I have installed all drivers for **Lenovo G50-70** but cannot find devices and so devices cannot discover it via Bluetooth. What is the problem?

Comment: "I searched in the Net very much and tried very methods for solving the issue"  My crystal ball is in the shop, and there's no point in us repeating what you've already tried.  Please edit your question to show your research -- include exactly what you've tried already, and what the results were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Download apropirate

http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/g50-70-notebook-lenovo

then install it and follow follow instruction:

1. Click Start, type "Services.msc” in the Search programs and files box, and then press ENTER,
2. Locate and double click the Bluetooth support service.
3. Click the Log On tab,
4. In the This account text box, type “Local Service”,
5. Set both Password fields blank,
6. Click Apply and then OK,
7. Restart the service and check.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be having visibility issues, there are two ways to try to discover devices.

**1. Search For Visible Devices From The Laptop:** When using search for devices from the laptop, make sure the other devices have their visibility enabled. Most devices now days are not visible, until the user enables visibility on the device. Even then, they are usually only visible for about 2 minutes. This should lead to a list of visible devices that your laptop can attempt to pair with.

**2. Use Your Devices To Search For The Laptop**: This is the same method as above. The only difference is make sure that visibility for you laptop is enabled so other devices can see it and attempt to pair with the laptop.

Comment: I have done those methods, but don't resolved.